# Microsoft SQL Server using dbconnect() with odbc in R Jupyter Datascience notebook on Docker image: certificate error & invalid connection string

Tags: python, r, sql-server, docker, jupyter-notebook

I am running the `Jupyter` datascience-notebook from https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks as a stand alone `Docker` image. I want to use this to access a `Microsoft SQL Server` database from both R and Python notebooks. I've extended the standard datascience-notebook by editing my Dockerfile to include the following for database access:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:85f615d5cafa
# Install Python libraries from requirements.txt file
COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --quiet --no-cache-dir --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" && \
    fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends procps ca-certificates \
    postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev gnupg
# openssh-server

# RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

# MS SQL Server requirements
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    export ACCEPT_EULA=Y && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18

ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"
```

From a Python notebook using `pyodbc` and `sqlalchemy`, this works fine, so I am confident that my credentials are correct:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

url = "mssql+pyodbc://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?{}&{}".format(
    os.getenv('CABOODLE_DB_USER'),
    os.getenv('CABOODLE_DB_PASSWORD'),
    os.getenv('CABOODLE_DB_HOST'),
    os.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_PORT"),
    os.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_NAME"),
    "driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server",
    "TrustServerCertificate=yes",
)
engine = create_engine(url, pool_size=1, max_overflow=1)
engine
```

However, I cannot get the R version to work. Here is the syntax I'm using. I've also tried hardcoding the values retrieved from Sys.getenv()

```
db <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 driver = 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',
                 server = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_HOST"),
                 database = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_NAME"),
                 trusted_connection = 'yes',
                 uid = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_USER"),
                 pwd= Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_PASSWORD"),
                 port = as.integer(Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_PORT"))
                 )
```

I get the following error

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:16000069:STORE routines::unregistered scheme:scheme=file][error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling stat(/opt/conda/ssl/certs)][error:16000069:STORE routines::unregistered scheme:scheme=file]  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute

There may be two problems here, the certificate error, and the invalid connection string.

In case it's relevant - Outside my Docker environment, I have access to the Microsoft SQL Server database from RStudio running on a Windows Desktop. In the windows environment, I'm told that the database credentials rely on Windows authentication. In that environment, this connection string works:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_HOST"),  Database = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_NAME"))
```

Comment: If you want to connect to a MySQL database then why are you trying to use Microsoft SQL Server drivers? MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server are completely different technologies, use completely different connection protocols and so require completely different database drivers.

Comment: Excellent question! This is all new to me and I conflated the two technologies. Microsoft SQL Server is the database I need to connect to.  I have edited the title and question accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The `TrustServerCertificate` and `Trusted_Connection` connection properties are controlling two different aspects of connection. The former is used with encrypted connections and is used to control whether or not an unsigned certificate (which is what SQL Server installs by default) should be trusted. The latter controls whether Windows/Active Directory/Kerberos authentication is used instead of SQL Logon details (username and password). Your pyodbc connection uses `TrustServerCertificate=yes`, you'll need something like that for RODBC as well.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment enabled me to solve the problem by using RODBC (not ODBC) library, and setting `TrustServerCertificate=yes`. I also needed to use odbcDriverConnect rather than odbcConnect() I will post the successful code below.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's the successful code

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)

# Define function to create a SQL Server connection string
create_conn_string <- function(server_name, database_name, user_name, password) {
  # Define the driver and server information
  driver <- "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"
  
  # Create the connection string
  conn_string <- paste0("Driver={", driver, "};",
                        "Server=", server, ";",
                        "Database=", database_name, ";",
                        "Uid=", user_name, ";",
                        "Pwd=", password, ";",
                        "Encrypt=yes;",
                        "TrustServerCertificate=yes;")

  return(conn_string)
}

# Example usage of the function
conn_string <- create_conn_string(server_name,
                                  database_name,
                                  user_name ,
                                  password)

# Connect to the database using the connection string
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(conn_string)
```

Comment: For clarity, is there no way to replicate this via arguments to `dbConnect()`, only by concatenating all of this into a connection string?

Comment: Answered my own question... there is such an argument to dbConnect per [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CDMConnector/vignettes/a04_DBI_connection_examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an alternate answer to the one from zmek that does not require (a) a separate function or (b) concatenating a connection string vs. using built-in args themselves.

I don't know what the cause of your initial error was, but this is equivalent to zmek's connection string but uses arguments instead:

```
db <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  driver = 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',
  server = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_HOST"),
  database = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_NAME"),
  trusted_connection = 'yes', # see note below about this; zmek omits it
  uid = Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_USER"),
  pwd= Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_PASSWORD"),
  port = as.integer(Sys.getenv("CABOODLE_DB_PORT"))
  TrustServerCertificate = "yes")
```

All I added was the `TrustServerCertificate` argument. Without it, I get the following error attempting to connect to my server:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1138: 00000
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate] 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722
```

Your error is about the connection string, so I suspect that as-posted, you have a couple issues going on. Could be a stretch, but look at [this github issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/483), which suggests that the values passed for `trusted_connection` can differ.

The main reason for this answer is that per [this list of example DBI connection methods](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CDMConnector/vignettes/a04_DBI_connection_examples.html), you can pass `TrusteServerCertificate` without having to define the separate function and make a single connection string.